# Postgresql Crosstab Not Working As Expected

Tags: postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, crosstab

I have a temp table with event counts organized by id and type. Their are 6 possible events. Here are results from id `234`.

```
SELECT * FROM _tmp_grouped WHERE id = 234;
```

[image]

I want to crosstab this so that the type becomes the column headers.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM crosstab('SELECT * FROM _tmp_grouped WHERE id = 234') 
    AS (id INT, prompt_shown_last BIGINT, prompt_shown BIGINT, prompt_dismissed_last BIGINT, prompt_dismissed BIGINT, prompt_allowed_last BIGINT, prompt_allowed BIGINT);
```

[image]

However, once I add additional ids, the crosstab results get funky.

[image]

If I do no filtering at all, the `prompt_shown_last` column is filled but all other columns are null. Additionally, each prompt_id has 6 rows for all 6 possible events.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by ordering the tmp_grouped query-

```
SELECT * FROM _tmp_grouped ORDER BY 1, 2
```